# WebSocket.ReceiveAsync - how to use ValueTask override?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

The `ReceiveAsync` method has 2 versions, one returning `Task<WebSocketReceiveResult>` and the other one returning `ValueTask<ValueWebSocketReceiveResult>`.

The first one takes `ArraySegment<byte>` as argument, the second one takes `Memory<byte>`.

Which one is better?
I'd go with the second one, as `Memory<T>` is newer and faster type than `ArraySegment<T>`.
However, the returned values are different.

`ValueWebSocketReceiveResult` misses `CloseStatus` and `CloseStatusDescription` needed for correct handling of closing handshake. How to get those values with the second version?

Is it worth it? Is it significantly faster or better in any way?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why those properties exist on both the Result type and on the Socket itself. Are the ones on the Socket (which exist no matter which Result type you're getting) inadequate?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OMG, thanks! I look at the code, and I don't see the thing in plain sight, of course they are fine, I just forgot about them. I looked at the code fragment I wanted to refactor and I was wondering where did they go ;) BTW, my refactoring is to isolate the transport from data processing, and moving those properties closer to the transport layer (the Socket) is the way to go.

Comment: What's more, the `Close` properties (of the `WebSocketReceiveResult`) had no references in my code, I just removed them and all tests (like 20 of them, including plenty of edge cases) pass like nothing happened.